My deploy script won't run. Any `console.log` after `module.exports` won't work
Here’s my deploy script:
const { network } = require("hardhat")
const {
  developmentChains,
  networkConfig,
  INITIAL_SUPPLY,
} = require("../helper-hardhat-config")

module.exports = async function ({ getNamedAccounts, deployments }) {
  console.log("Here")
  const { deploy, log } = deployments
  const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts()

  const MethERC20 = await deploy("OurToken", {
    from: deployer,
    args: [INITIAL_SUPPLY],
    log: true,
    waitConfirmations: network.config.blockConfirmations || 1,
  })

  console.log(`METH deployed at ${MethERC20.address}`)

  if (
    !developmentChains.includes(network.name) &&
    process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY
  ) {
    log("Verifying.....")
    await verify(MethERC20.address, [INITIAL_SUPPLY])
  }

  module.exports.tags = ["all", "MethERC20"]
}


You’ve to attach the tags after the function definition.
So, your revised script would be:
const { network } = require("hardhat")
const {
  developmentChains,
  networkConfig,
  INITIAL_SUPPLY,
} = require("../helper-hardhat-config")

module.exports = async function ({ getNamedAccounts, deployments }) {
  console.log("Here")
  const { deploy, log } = deployments
  const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts()

  const MethERC20 = await deploy("OurToken", {
    from: deployer,
    args: [INITIAL_SUPPLY],
    log: true,
    waitConfirmations: network.config.blockConfirmations || 1,
  })

  console.log(`METH deployed at ${MethERC20.address}`)

  if (
    !developmentChains.includes(network.name) &&
    process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY
  ) {
    log("Verifying.....")
    await verify(MethERC20.address, [INITIAL_SUPPLY])
  }
}

// Attach tags after the function definition
module.exports.tags = ["all", "MethERC20"]

Edit - After reviewing your GitHub repo that you shared in the comments:

You've to rename the scripts folder to deploy.

In your OurToken.sol contract, the name of the contract should be OurToken (instead of MethERC20) because that's what you're using in your deploy script, otherwise it won't be able to find the corresponding OurToken artifact while deploying.



Ohhhh! I didn't see that. I spent days on this. What does the mean? module.exports.tags = ["all", "MethERC20"]

I have corrected it, it is not run

Can you share your code via GitHub repo?

And, how exactly are you running the deploy script?

I use yarn hardhat run deploy/01-deploy-token.js
Here is the github repo: https://github.com/PatrickAlphaC/hardhat-erc20-fcc

You've to run yarn hardhat deploy instead.

I got this Compiled 7 Solidity files successfully (evm target: paris). Done in 6.35s.

Are you running yarn hardhat compile or yarn hardhat deploy?

yarn hardhat deploy

I was shock when I saw  Compiled 7 Solidity files successfully (evm target: paris). Done in 6.35s.

When, I'm executing yarn hardhat deploy. I'm getting: deploying "OurToken" (tx: 0x167069b2c1ff48ced4891bcc9964738e61f35af2c80ac024bd4a5aee3b3e6eb0)...: deployed at 0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3 with 1225998 gas ourToken deployed at 0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3 ✨  Done in 1.98s. output in the terminal though.

What could be the problem on my end?

How did you get/compile your node modules

Can you try deleting node_modules folder and yarn.lock file? And then, run yarn install.

I have tried it but it is not working. Should I push it to the GitHub and send the link?

Sure, please send.

https://github.com/EddiePumpin/hardhat-ERC20

@EddiePumpin, I've edited my answer to add more details. Please check.

Thanks mate, I worked. I appreciate your time and effort.
Please, what is the effect of naming the folder scripts instead of deploy

Also, does it mean that the deploy scripts is for OurToken.sol?

Yes, the deploy script is for OurToken.sol and the reason for naming the folder deploy is that the yarn hardhat deploy command finds the deploy script in the  deploy folder and if it's not available it just deploys it using artifact, that's why you were just seeing Compiled 7 Solidity files successfully (evm target: paris). Done in 6.35s. in the console, but after naming the folder to deploy, you can see the actual logs that you are using in your script.

Kindly accept the answer if it helped you, so that it could potentially help others too.

Thanks man. What about the scripts folder? Some folders are named scripts, what is the differences?

You’re welcome. You can run the scripts using different command like: yarn hardhat run scripts/scriptFileName.js.

Yeah, I know the command for running scripts but I don't know the function of the scripts folder. Is for deploying or what?

It's generally for interacting with the contract like for calling functions and all.

Sorry for asking too much question.
I am a newbie in this niche with zero understanding/knowledge of codes.
Please, break it down. Or is there any docs I can read?

No worries. You can refer to the official Hardhat documentation.

Thanks, I appreciate

You're welcome. Happy coding!
